# Can you catch an exception thrown during exception handling?

Tags: exception, d

I'm reading *The D Programming Language*, and it says that `throw` looks to see if there's an existing exception chain (of exceptions being handled), and if there is, attaches the new exception to that.

But what if the second exception could be handled before it escapes the handler of the first? For example, if the `catch` that caught the first calls another function, which causes an exception but could handle it. Seems like the catcher would have to know about what exceptions could be called internally by any code it calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception chaining only occurs if the second thrown exception escapes the `catch` block. If it is handled within the `catch` block, whether right in the block or a callee, nothing out-of-the-ordinary happens - the first exception is handled normally.

You can check this yourself with a simple example:

```
class E : Exception { this() { super("E"); } }
class F : Exception { this() { super("F"); } }

void main()
{
    try
        throw new E;
    catch (E e)
    {
        try
            throw new F;
        catch (F f)
            {}
    }
}
```

This program will exit normally, as both exceptions are handled silently.

Comment: and what about those thrown in `finally` blocks

Comment: Same, it is only chained if the second exception is not caught. Note that you cannot put a catch statement inside a finally block, so it needs to be in another function.